# php - Adding multiple values to an array using foreach

Tags: php

I'm saving multiple values on form submit to an array using foreach. The below logic was working fine before php 8 update.

Please let me know what needs to be done to make it work again.

```
$batch = $this->input->post('batch_id');
$activity_selected = $this->input->post('activity_selected');
$characteristics = array_values($this->input->post('characteristics'));
$user_id=$this->session->userdata('userid');
foreach($activity_selected as $key => $val) 
{
    $dataSet[] = array (
            'batch_id' => $batch_id,
            'activity_id' => $activity_selected[$key],
            'characteristics' => implode(',', $characteristics[$key]),
            'user_id' => $user_id,
    );  
}
$this->person->insertdata($dataSet,$batch);
```

Getting this error

> ERROR - 2222 Oct 2121 11:47:24 --> Severity: Compile Error --> Cannot use [] for reading D:\xampp\htdocs*** 122

> ERROR - 2222 Oct 2121 11:47:32 --> Severity: error --> Exception: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given D:\xampp\htdocs*** 108
> ERROR - 2222 Oct 2121 11:47:32 --> Severity: error --> Exception: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given D:\xampp\htdocs*** 108

Comment: Doesn't work is not a helpful description of your problem. Do you get error messages (have you looked in the error logs for any?) What does it do? Whats does it not do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: So did you look in the error logs, there are sometines clues to the a 500 error

Comment: Out of interest, what version of PHP were you using before moving to PHP8

Comment: ERROR - 2222 Oct 2121 11:47:32 --> Severity: error --> Exception: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given D:\xampp\htdocs\*** 108

Comment: Getting error in above format. Earlier the php version was 7.3 I believe

Comment: Well that basically says you are passing a String variable to `implode()` and not an array. I doubt that is due to the PHP version change. Something else has changed

Comment: `$characteristics` is expected to be a two dimensional array in your code, but it is one dimensional.  Your question fails to include the helpful Debugging Details of presenting the POSTed data.  We cannot see what the other error is coming from.  Ideally, you should be declaring `$dataSet` before the loop or checking `if (isset($dataSet)) ` before inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to PHP 8, the following code would throw only a warning and return `NULL`

See here. https://3v4l.org/vuNBL

```
$characteristics['key'] = 'string';
$key = 'key';

var_dump(implode(',', $characteristics[$key]));

// Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /in/q6EPW on line 6
// NULL
```

Since PHP 8, the warning is now elevated to a Fatal error

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given`

There are a couple of ways you can resolve this, the easiest would be to check if the value is an array, and if not pass an empty array.

```
implode(',', is_array($characteristics[$key]) ? $characteristics[$key] : []);

// string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a massive amount you could do to that code, you could get rid of the need to have an incremental variable ($i) by using foreach($items as $key => $value) and using $key instead of $i.